# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I work on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. I was testing websockets on my server, when I noticed that var/www/error_log was about 5GB large, filling up my diskspace. I (stupidly) tried to view its contents using vim, which froze everything. I am currently trying to restart the environment, but the restart keeps timing out. What can I do to get it back up again?

Comment: can you ssh to your machine from another terminal, then `ps ax` to list all the processes.  Identify `vim` and `kill -9 <process id>`

Comment: I cannot connect via `eb ssh`

All I get is

`INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/aws-eb-environment ec2-user@x.x.x.x`

Comment: Try to restart an underlying EC2 machine because Beanstalk most likely tries to gradually stop the service and then do a soft reset which is not possible while the system is not responding

Comment: @riverfall how can I do that? I tried "Restart App Servers" in the Actions dropdown twice but that didn't change anything. It just tried to update my environment for 15 minutes and timed out afterwards

Comment: @mo_st navigate to AWS EC2 console and search for the name of your Beanstalk application. The underlying EC2 machine should have the same name (I suppose your installation consists of only one VM)

Comment: Connect to the EC2 console, select the instance and select restart

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it!

Comment: 2022: using the web console there is an option to restart the app server. I will search the shell or api equivalence

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to restart the underlying EC2 machine, by accessing the AWS EC2 Console.

I cannot thank @riverfall and @sébastien-stormacq enough for helping me! These things tend to get very stressful